# pycharm configurations lost after closing project

Tags: ide, pycharm

When I create a Run Configuration for a project, pycharm will remember it as long as this project is opened in my IDE, or when I open it via the 'welcome to pycharm' window.

However, when I close my project and reopen it, I can’t find the config I saved before. Is there a way to find it again? Is it not saved in the .idea folder? (I'm running pycharm on mac os)

Comment: The .idea folder is created for each project inside the project root folder. Which configuration are you talking about? The color theme,... or the virtual environment settings,...
You can export your favorite settings as a `.jar` file and it will be shared across projects.

Comment: I'm talking about the environment settings, i.e. working directory, parameters, interpreter options etc. .jar sounds like what you'd use in intelli-J is there a python equivalent for pycharm?

Comment: The working directory is bound to the project so it changes at every project you create. The settings of Pycharm can be exported as a `.jar` file I confirm but this will not solve your issue I think (you can check for yourself in the main menu `Export Settings...`)

Comment: @sousben Seems that you're talking about `Run Configuration`. How do you create it? Maybe this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html could help

Comment: @user2235698 yes that’s what I’m talking about but the documentation doesn’t answer my question

Comment: Have you fixed this issue @sousben ? I'm experiencing the same

Comment: no I haven't... and most of the suggestions or answers here miss the mark, I probably didn't phrase my question well enough originally. please feel free to add an answer here if you find it on your side

Answer (score -1):

As @Eskapp said, run configurations are saved on per-project basis. If you want to share them between projects, please look at this topic: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206600965-Export-Import-Run-Configurations-

Comment: Hi, I’ve edited the question to make it clearer. I am not trying to share a config between projects, only I don’t want to lose it if when I reopen a project